# Express js route with different ids

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, web

Im using node js with express lib.There are pages like localhost/page/1,localhost/page/2. They are pretty similar but some information must change depending on page id. Im redirecting to this pages with form submit.

```
<form method='GET' action='/order_page/" + order.id[i] + "'><input type='submit' value='move'></form>
```

and in my server js

```
app.get('order_page/:id', checkUserSession, function(request, response) {
    response.send(req.id);
});
```

it redirects and gives me error Cannot GET /order_page/6

What's the best solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add a "/" before "order_page/:id"

```
app.get('/order_page/:id', checkUserSession, function(request, response) {
response.send(req.id);});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `/` before the order_page  :

```
app.get('/order_page/:id', checkUserSession, function(request, response) {
    response.send(req.id);
});
```